# An insignificant number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function value

Tags: sql, xml

An insignificant number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function value. I am receiving this error on the line WHERE VendorID = @Update.value( and I am not sure what is causing this error.

```
DECLARE @Update XML = '
<Updates>
<Contact VendorID="2">
<LastName>Name1</LastName>
<FirstName>Name2</FirstName>
</Contact>
<Contact VendorID="12">
<LastName>Name3</LastName>
<FirstName>Name4</FirstName>
</Contact>
</Updates>
'

UPDATE Vendors
SET LName = @Update.value(
'(/Updates/Contact/LastName[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
FName = @Update.value(
'(/Updates/Contact/FirstName[1]', 'varchar(50)')
WHERE VendorID = @Update.value(
'(/Updates/Contact/@VendorID[1]' 'int');
```

'int' at the end is also showing "incorrect syntax error". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error at the end is caused by a missing comma. Look at the two lines above that one - the ones that also start with `(/Updates`.

Comment: The word, *insignificant*, makes no sense here.  Are you sure the actual error didn't use *insufficient*?

Comment: Perhaps the error message was produced by a non-English-speaking programmer. It wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: You are missing a , and ) in you code like Ken said.  
`UPDATE Vendors SET LName = @Update.value( '(/Updates/Contact/LastName)[1]', 'varchar(50)'), FName = @Update.value( '(/Updates/Contact/FirstName)[1]', 'varchar(50)') WHERE VendorID = @Update.value( '(/Updates/Contact/@VendorID)[1]', 'int');`   
You can use this as well.   
`UPDATE V set v.LName = T.c.value('(LastName)[1]', 'varchar(50)'), v.FName = T.c.value('(FirstName)[1]', 'varchar(50)') from Vendors as V join @Update.nodes('/Updates/Contact') as T(c) on v.VendorID = T.c.value('(@VendorID)[1]', 'int');`